# Selenium JUnit DOM Testing - Problem with counting Dynamic rows

Tags: selenium, junit, gui

I have a DOM structure "**div > table id = 't1' > tbody > tr**" (count of tr changes on resize)
The javascript function changes the number of rows on resizing the browser. I want to count number of rows for the table.

I am using the following code

```
   final String tablePath = "//../div/table[1]";
   final int size = Browser.getElements(By.xpath(tablePath).tagName("tbody")).size();
   System.out.println("row count=" + size);
```

How will I show the rowcount which is changing dynamically?

Answer (score 2):

The `size()` function returns the number of elements found with the `getElements()` function, I expect it to return just one table element. The value of size equals 1.

I would get the HTML inside the table and count the occurrences of `<tr>` or something unique per row, expecting you do not have nested tables with rows inside the initial table. The code for that would look something like this:

```
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.id("t1"));
String tableContent = table.getAttribute("innerHTML");
int count = StringUtils.countMatches(tabelContent, "<tr>");
```

After you change the window size you will have to get the `innerHTML` again and count the rows to see if it actually changed or not.